# odata 4 many-to-many relation ships

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2

Using `ODataController` In one to many to many or in many-to-many relationship, how can I GET child of child entities.

For example in the OData 4 Sample Service here:

https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/blob/master/Scenarios/TripPin/src/webapi/ODataSamples.WebApiService/Controllers/PeopleController.cs

I need to know how to implement something like:

```
public class PeopleController : ODataController
{
    ...

    [ODataRoute("People({key})/Trips/PlanItems)]
    public IQuerable<PlanItems> GetPlanItems([FromODataUri] string key])
}
```

That means I want to retrieve all PlanItems for a Person.

Unfortunately, all methods implement `[ODataRoute("People({key})/Trips({tripId})/PlanItems)]` only

Answer (score 0):

The URL convention `.../People(key)/Trips/PlanItems` is not valid as you can see from the error message if you try "The request URI is not valid. Since the segment 'Trips' refers to a collection, this must be the last segment in the request URI or it must be followed by an function or action that can be bound to it otherwise all intermediate segments must refer to a single resource." So the alternative is using URL `.../People(key)/Trips?$expand=PlanItems`

Comment: I know that I can get PlanItems only by using actions or functions. $expand does not return PlanItems themselves. Are there any other way to get PlanItems without actions?